# I get error : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" in use procedure oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new in oracle , when I write this code I get error : PLS-00103 .please help me
my code is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LCR_REP_PROFILE_DETAILE
  (VAR_NAME     IN VARCHAR2,    
   VRA_EFF_DATE IN DATE)              
AS
  VAR_FORMULA VARCHAR2(4000);
  VAR_BALANCE NUMBER ;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    SELECT QRY, BALANCE   
    INTO VAR_FORMULA, VAR_BALANCE   
    FROM  TBL_LCR_QRY TLQ                 
    WHERE NAME = VAR_NAME              
      AND ID= i 
      AND EFF_DATE = VAR_EFF_DATE;

    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VAR_BALANCE INTO VAR_FORMULA ;  
    INSERT INTO TBL_LCR_PROFILE_DETAILE(ID,NAME,FORMULA,EFF_DATE,BALANCE )
    SELECT CODE,VAR_NAME,VAR_QRY,VAR_EFF_DATE,VAR_BALANCE    
    FROM DUAL ;
    COMMIT;

  END LOOP ;
END;
```

my error is :

```
9/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/22     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "VAR_EFF_DATE": invalid identifier
17/5      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
17/23     PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
18/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
19/34     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "VAR_EFF_DATE": invalid identifier
```

please help me  .

I want to fix my errors

Comment: `execute immediate` expects a SQL command or a PL/SQL block that it can run, but you are trying to execute `balance` which as far as I can make out is a number.

Comment: @William Robertson please take a look again my edit code ?

Comment: Maybe you misstyped `var_eff_date`at the top? But you are still trying to execute `VAR_BALANCE` as a command, which won't work. You must follow the `execute immediate` keywords with a string which represents a valid SQL or PL/SQL command. You can't `execute immediate 42`.

Answer (score 0):

Bunch of errors. See comments I wrote within your code. Fix that first, and then see whether it works or not. I can't run it to verify, I don't have your tables nor data, and you didn't provide any.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LCR_REP_PROFILE_DETAILE
  (VAR_NAME     IN VARCHAR2(4000),    --> no size here!
   VRA_EFF_DATE IN DATE)              --> VRA? Did you mean VAR?
AS
  VAR_QRY VARCHAR2(4000);
  VAR_BALANCE NUMBER ;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    SELECT NAME, QRY, BALANCE   
    INTO VAR_NAME, VAR_QRY, VAR_BALANCE   --> you can't select into VAR_NAME, it is IN parameter
    FROM  TBL_LCR_QRY TLQ                 
    WHERE NAME = 'VAR_NAME'               --> remove single quotes   
      AND ID= i 
      AND VAR_EFF_DATE = EFF_DATE;

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR_QRY);

    -- what is this supposed to do? Should've probably been
    -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VAR_QRY INTO VAR_BALANCE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE BALANCE, QRY INTO VAR_BALANCE, VAR_QRY ;  

    --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR_NAME ||'     '||VAR_BALANCE);

    INSERT INTO TBL_LCR_PROFILE_DETAILE(ID,NAME,FORMULA,EFF_DATE,BALANCE )
    SELECT CODE,VAR_NAME,VAR_QRY,VAR_EFF_DATE,VAR_BALANCE    --> this can't work; CODE was never declared
    FROM DUAL ;
    COMMIT;

  END LOOP ;
END;
```

Comment: I save the changes but I get the same errors again

Comment: As I said: provide test case and your new procedure code wo that we'd see what you really have and be able to run your code. Do it by editing original question, not as a comment.

Comment: I changed AS you said me but I get the same errors again .please take a look my edit original question .

Comment: As far as I can see, you did **not** fix everything I commented, but managed to produce some new errors. SELECT now selects 3 values into 2 variables. What is dynamic SQL supposed to do? Once again: provide test case, otherwise this is pretty much useless discussion.